# WooCommerce: remove sample & dummy data

Tags: database, woocommerce-offtopic

I set up and configured a WordPress site using WooCommerce. When I was developing, I imported the dummy data for testing.

How can I remove the dummy data to delivery?

Answer (score 1):

Even though it's dummy data, there is nothing special about it compared to actual data other than the fact that it's all made up for testing purposes.

I assume that you only imported dummy data for testing and not actual data. If so, I'd recommend that you manually delete the dummy data through WordPress.

Comment: yes, i have already remove it by manual. I just ask because i want to delivery a clean package. Thanks

Comment: @n2lose That should be enough since permanently deleting the dummy data through WordPress also removes it from the database. You can also go through your database and check the data in the WooCommerce tables, but I don't think that is necessary for this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

A very useful plugin in this situation is WooCommerce Remove All Products. You just need to install and run it, then all of the existing products will be gone. You will have do delete your product categories manually, however, but I think that's much easier than deleting both categories and products by yourself.